# Suggestions on setting up a practice room

Tags: instruments, setup

We are setting up a simple practice room in our house, the room is quiet small approximately 30 square meters. Here's the layout.

[image: Practice Setup]

As you can see their is no amps because of space constraints, electric drum kit for noise issues. I really dont know if this setup works.

We are not a professional musicians, this is just a hobby and for fun. 
And probably use this setup for small parties like birthdays.

Comment: Do you have AUXs set up for everyone on the mixer so they can hear themselves and each other?

Comment: The mixer has an AUX output on each channel. Does the speakers setup is not enough?

Comment: Probably not especially if one instrument is much louder than the others. Setting ups AUXs and using them with headphones or in-ear monitors lets everyone hear at all instruments at level that is good for them without affecting the mixer output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned mics. You may need 2 or 3, if you are playing ; listening with headphones, bare voices won't be heard.

30 sq.m. is a nice size, and while the drum kit will take up valuable space, I think there is room for a couple of practice amps at least. 60 watt with 12" speakers will be plenty. Then the vox can go through the p.a.  With the amps spread out, there will be a more spacial feel, with guitar and bass coming from different directions. I also feel that using headphones, especially if you also use wired mics,etc., will end up with spaghetti all over the floor (too many cables).

Ideally the p.a. speakers would be hung on the wall, but then you will probably have feedback problems with mics - if you use them.

Also, a source to play backing tracks (and ordinary ones !) is useful. This, in stereo, will need inputs to plug into - unless it has its own speakers - which CAN go on the wall.

With the recording facility, you can always use the send output from the amps to get guitar/bass signals to the deck.

Answer (score 0):

As you have an electronic kit the setup should be fine. I'm not sure I agree with needing headphones for monitoring. You have said noise is an issue so I assume you won't be overly loud. With a good balance and everyone taking responsibility for their own relative level, it should be fine.